# In exe built by cx_Freeze, "asksaveasfile" and "askopenfile" are not working.

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have two built in buttons dedicated for browsing and saving the output. Its working fine in console. But when I built exe out of it, the two buttons simply do not open the explorer in order to browse or save.
Here is the cx_freeze code

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
 base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("cypher.py", base=base,icon="icon2.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
name = "Classical-Cypher",
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","PIL"], "include_files":["icon2.ico"]}},
version = "BETA",
description = "Encryption and decryption of classical cyphers",
executables = executables
)
```

Building shows no error!
The image of the GUI is [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErEZi.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I sort this out!
I have used the following in the original script

`import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog`

And in the cx_Freeze script,

```
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","PIL","tkinter.filedialog"], "include_files":["icon2.ico"]}},
```

Done ! :)